# Shell Script from Unix not running on other OS

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script working on SCO Unix 5.0.6. The problem is when I copy the script to another machine with SCO Unix 5.0.7 (and also other OS) then it is not running. It shows a syntax error.

Note that when I copy all instructions and paste them in command line then they work perfectly. However, as I said they are not working as one script file.

As example in the script I have:

```
case "${MODUS}" in
```

And I get the below error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '$'in\r''
```

Base on the error it seems to me something is added at the end of each instruction.

In some cases when the error is at the end of the instruction I can fix the problem. I add a space and #(to consider the rest line as comment) at the end of each instruction. Then it works. However, the problem is that I cannot do that for all instructions. In some cases the error is in middle of the instruction and then (space#) not working.

Please let me know what is the reason for the error and how can I fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your script has DOS line endings, the error even mentions it: `in\r`. You need to remove them.

Comment: How can I prevent this, when I copy the file?

Comment: Don't use Notepad to "copy" files? You didn't say how are you doing the copying.

Comment: No, I don't think you do.

Comment: You can strip trailing carriage returns with `sed -i 's/\r$//' file`

Comment: @glennjackman - are you sure that GNU sed notation works in SCO Unix's sed? I'm suspicious of the `-i` without a null OPTARG, as well as support for `\r`.

Comment: Not at all. I have no access to a SCO box to test.

Comment: A bit hackish, but this might suffice:`sed -i "" "$(printf 's/\\\r$//')" file` ... assuming of course that SCO's default shell understands `$(..)`.  :-)

Comment: Doesn't SCO have `tr`?